# Legally parsing browser history

Tags: browser, browser-history

I want to create a service that suggests things based on the sites one has visited. It would be a user controllable process. In other words, the service would start "recording / suggesting" from the users browsing history only tell the service to start (and stop).

I'm not looking for hacks or potentially illegal methods. Technically would this be possible with Javascript as (say) something like a bookmarklet? Or would it need something with more fundamental browser access like an extension?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an extension to get access to this much data and it'll have to be custom for each browser.